# Why isn't caching activating in my Rails dev environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

I'm attempting to setup caching in development using Dalli and memcache.

I've installed memcached and can access it from the Rails console"

```
> Rails.cache.write 'test', 'asdfasdf'
Cache write: test
Dalli::Server#connect 127.0.0.1:11211
=> 360287970189639680

> Rails.cache.read 'test'
Cache read: test
=> "asdfasdf"
```

I've installed the memcachier and dalli gems:

**gemfile.rb**

```
gem 'dalli'
gem 'memcachier'
```

and I've updated development.rb to instruct caching to activate:

**development.rb**

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.cache_store = :dalli_store, '127.0.0.1'
```

### However I still can't seem to make fragment caching work...

However if I take one of my view files and wrap the contents in a cache block it doesn't seem to affect the page rendering:

```
- cache @page do
  %h1 @page.title
  %p @page.contents
```

#### I don't believe this is caching

If I check the server logs there aren't any fewer database calls. I would also expect that since the cache key is only dependent on the `@page` model, any changes to the template would not show in the browser but they do. If I alter the contents and refresh the browser it immediately updates.

What am I missing, why isn't this caching?

### Edit - I think this is perhaps to do with *explicit dependencies*

In the [cache digests documentation](https://github.com/rails/cache_digests#explicit-dependencies) there is a reference to explicit dependencies and templates that can't be derived. I think that may be my problem, the console is showing messages such as:

```
18:39:10 web.1  | Couldn't find template for digesting: pages/magazine_header.html
18:39:10 web.1  | Cache digest for magazines/next_previous_nav.html: 5249e7d094aafe2365a097d8ca543dd1
18:39:10 web.1  | Couldn't find template for digesting: layout_partials/layout_partial.html
18:39:10 web.1  | Cache digest for pages/show.html: 314c806fcbb207d41137bc46f0856db0
18:39:10 web.1  | Cache read: views/pages/199-20140614104931344003000/314c806fcbb207d41137bc46f0856db0
18:39:10 web.1  | Read fragment views/pages/199-20140614104931344003000/314c806fcbb207d41137bc46f0856db0 (1.2ms)
18:39:10 web.1  |   Rendered pages/show.html.haml within layouts/magazine (8.4ms)
```

I'm not immediately sure how to resolve this but will be investigating...

Comment: In your logs do you see statements like "Read fragment views/...", "Cache write: views/...", "Write fragment views/...", "Cache read: views/..."?

Comment: ahah - yes. Along with this message... ` Couldn't find template for digesting: pages/magazine_header.html
 web.1  | Cache digest for magazines/next_previous_nav.html: 5249e7d094a7d8ca543dd1
 web.1  | Couldn't find template for digesting: layout_partials/layout_partial.html
web.1  | Cache digest for pages/show.html: 314c806fcbb207d41137bc46f0856db0
 web.1  | Cache read: views/pages/199-20140614104931344003000/314c806fcbb206f0856db0
 web.1  | Read fragment views/pages/199-20140614104931344003000/314c806f46f0856db0 (1.1ms)`  - off to google...

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4 isn't too smart in figuring out template dependencies using implicit template rendering. It's mentioned in the documentation you linked. You'll need to use a special comment format in your views:

```
<%# Template Dependency: pages/magazine_header %>
```

It can also help to use the explicit form of template rendering. Rails will most likely be able to infer the correct partials by itself.

```
# change this:
<%= render 'pages/magazine_header' %>

# into this:
<%= render partial: 'pages/magazine_header' %>
```

The good news is that since Rails 5.0.4 and 5.1.3, [implicit template rendering got a lot smarter](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/25817). I suspect using those versions will fix your issue too.